# Reference for Coefficient Extraction of Multiple Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

In a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229328/help-finding-a-closed-form), the final answer is obtained by coefficent extraction of the quadruple sum.

$$=n![x^n]\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{r}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{(2k+1)^{h}}{h!}\binom{r+m}{m}x^{h+m}\right)$$

$$=n!\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{r}{k}\binom{r+m}{m}(-1)^{k+m}\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{(2k+1)^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}$$

it would seem that letting $n=h+m$, helped in the extraction by rewriting all $h$ terms as $n-m$.  Ultimately I understand how it works, but I am looking for a paper or book that explains this type of move of coefficient extraction with multiple summations.  I checked [Wilf's Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf) and didn't find what I was looking for, and I've seen some texts explain the coefficient extraction process and I understand that, but i just need a book or paper with this type of coefficient extraction.

Comment: The well known text Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik has a section on generating functions (it's section 5.4 in the second edition). They have several examples along the lines you seem to be asking.

Comment: This sounds good.  I just check my university library and they have it in stock so I will get in on Monday and see what I can find.  I should have kept Knuth in mind....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* We can iteratively move the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ through each of the sums by respecting powers of $x$ whenever we met them.

> We obtain this way
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{n![x^n]}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{r}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{(2k+1)^{h}}{h!}\binom{r+m}{m}x^{h+m}\right)}\\
> &=n![x^n]\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}\binom{r}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{(2k+1)^{h}}{h!}\binom{r+m}{m}x^{h}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=n!\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{m=0}^{n}[x^{n-m}]\left(\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}\binom{r}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{(2k+1)^{h}}{h!}\binom{r+m}{m}x^{h}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=n!\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{r}{k}\binom{r+m}{m}(-1)^{k+m}\left(\frac{1}{2^r}\right)\frac{(2k+1)^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we exchange the inners sums and factor out $x^m$ from the innermost sum as preparation for the next step.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)
  \end{align*}
  We also set the upper limit of sum with index $m$ to $n$ since the exponent of $x^{n-m}$ is non-negative.
- In (3) we select the coeffcient of $x^{n-m}$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Many thanks for accepting all the answers.